# gridview checkbox problem asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, findcontrol

I am trying to implement a checkbox within gridview,

The job of this checkbox is to verify a record,

When this verify button is pressed, all items with a checked checkbox are inputted into the database

This is my code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {

             CheckBox cbox = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("Verify"));

            if (cbox.Equals(true))
            {
                String DraftsText = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("numDrafts")).Text;
                String TCtext = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("numTC")).Text;

                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    //Header trs = new Header();
                    // GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("numTC");
                    if (TCtext != "" && DraftsText != "")
                    {

                        //  try
                        //  {
                        string date = row.Cells[4].Text;

                        DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                        string dateFormatted = dateTime.ToString("d-MMM-yy");

                        string unit = row.Cells[5].Text;
                        string currency = row.Cells[6].Text;
                        string totalFC = row.Cells[7].Text;
                        string totalDC = row.Cells[8].Text;
                        int d = Convert.ToInt32(DraftsText);
                        int tc = Convert.ToInt32(TCtext);


                        hdr = new Header(d, tc, dateFormatted, unit, currency, totalFC, totalDC);
                        hdr.InsertFCTC(hdr);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I might be going at this the wrong way but in the if (cbox.Equals(true))
its giving me an exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea what i can do to solve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  `if (cbox.Equals(true))` should be  `if (cbox.Checked)`

Since your `cbox is a checkbox object` it can't be used to compare, so you have to use the `cbox` `Checked` Property, which will return `true/false`

Comment: still gives me Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That checkbox is not found when you are trying to finding using row.FindControl... You have to post aspx markup to find the issue.

Comment: ok problem solved, i was passing the wrong textbox id & the if should have been as you said THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You receive a NullPointerException because the suggested checkbox wasn't found! Or the direct cast into an instance of type CheckBox doesn't worked as expected.

Comment: ok problem solved, i was passing the wrong textbox id & the if should have been if (cbox.Checked)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to something like this and retry:

```
CheckBox cbox = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("Verify"));

            if (cbox != null && cbox.Checked)
            {
....
}
```